# SVG not displayed when using html2canvas

Tags: svg, html2canvas, canvg

I am working on a project where I need to generate a pdf file (onclick saveFile as PDF) on the client side as some data are not to be sent to the server. I have read about these options available; fileSaver.js and html2canvas, and none seem to help. I also want to point out that I am not so good with javascript. 
Here is my js code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#saveOutput").click(function() {
            $("#Screenshot").html2canvas({ 
                onrendered: function(canvas) {
                    var png = canvas.toDataURL()
                    window.open(png);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

and my Html

```
<div id="Screenshot">
    <p>This is it</p>
    <svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="250" height="250" style="height: 250px; width: 250px;">       
          <circle id="1" cx="100" cy="100" r="25" fill="#A52A2A"></circle>
    </svg>
</div>
<div id="content">
    <a class="button" id="saveOutput" href="#">Save as File</a>
</div>
```

Why cant it shows the SVG file? How can these files be converted to Canvas?could someone shows me with code sample? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: To plot the svg's you've to use "canvg.js", it converts all the svgs into <canvas> elements refer [canvg.js](https://github.com/gabelerner/canvg)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Like already said in other answers: the latest html2canvas support svg elements.

But apparently CSS is not applied and has a bug when is set the css "width" style and svg "width" attribute.

Before the screenshot, I added a treatment to svg elements.

```
var svgElements = document.body.querySelectorAll('svg');
svgElements.forEach(function(item) {
    item.setAttribute("width", item.getBoundingClientRect().width);
    item.setAttribute("height", item.getBoundingClientRect().height);
    item.style.width = null;
    item.style.height= null;
});
```

Edit: added height based on comment

Comment: Thanks! This solved a problem I was having that other answers didn't solve.

Comment: I found that the attribute width and **height** were both required for svg element to be captured.

Comment: thank you @ClaytonBell. The height addition was key

Comment: i have only one SVG element, I tried the above but still not working

Comment: love you! I had same issue after Image screenshot.spent around 2-3 hrs on it.Your solution worked 100% for mi. Thanks

Comment: It doesn't work for me either.

Comment: Doesn't work for me even though height and width are set as attributes. Maybe this is also related to top, right, etc. styles?

Comment: The SVG elements are rendered in the image when I use Html2Canvas, except svg <Image> tag.

<image y="2" transform="translate(0,0)" height="28" width="28" x="28" xlink:href="/content/adv/Control/2.png" display="block"></image>

Any special handling needed for svg Image tags ?

Answer (score 7):

- Solution 1 : You can use latest html2canvas which will support svg
  elements.
- Solution 2 : Before calling html2canvas function you can    convert
  all existing svg elements into canvas elements, which is    supported
  by html2canvas. For this conversion you can use canvg.js.

Comment: On StackOverflow we care about high quality questions and answers. 
Please read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) before you answer a question again. This will ensure that your answers live up to Stackoverflow's standards.

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.

Comment: I am using the latest version as of `v1.0.0-alpha.12`, however, I still can't render `SVG` tags, even very simple graphs.

Comment: Well, I do can render svg but I can only render `svg` tags when width specified.

Comment: @AGamePlayer Thank you! I resolve the problem adding "width" to the svg

Answer (score 2):

Faced the same issue.

Moved all the CSS into a container element (`div`) and applied the CSS (in my case, `position:absolute;`) to the container element instead of the svg element.

As Isabella Lopes has pointed out correctly, height and width need to be applied as attributes and not styles.

Answer (score 0):

in my case I had a margin-top, which moved the svg outside of the visible area (worked perfect in html). Maybe helpful for someone... just replace margin by padding of the parent element.

Answer (score -1):

try to download the latest version of html2canvas on the following link

https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/releases

at the moment it's version 0.5.0-alpha1

i tried it and it works for me.

Comment: I tried 5.0 alpha 1 and v1.0.0-rc.3 and my SVGs are just blank.

Comment: @Kyle I had the same problem with fontawesome icons and version 1.0.0-rc.3 and i added `style="width: 20px"` or whatever your width is for each svg and it worked.

Comment: @Apostolos to which element we had to apply that styling! SVG ?

Comment: i think yes. it's been a while :) but i think yes, at svg