# Error loading svg data with html2canvas and jspdf

Tags: javascript, html, svg, printing

I have a very simple svg

```
<div id="printId">
    test
    <svg height="100" width="100">
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" />
    </svg> 
</div>
```

and trying to print it with html2canvas and jspdf. But whatever I do I get an error

```
Error loading svg data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20height%3D%22100%22%20width%3D%22100%22%20style%3D%22-webkit-writing-mode%3A%20horizontal-tb%3B%20-webkit-user-modify%3A%20read-only%3B%20-webkit-user-drag%3A%20auto%3B%20-web
Oe.error @ html2canvas-1.1.2.min.js:20
```

and `test.pdf` file with just word `test` in it.

I googled this for about 3 hours, and in every place people recommend [settings `width/height` atributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32481054/svg-not-displayed-when-using-html2canvas). Which, as you can see, doesn't help in my case.
I've simplified it as much as I could. Here is the full index.html I use:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <div id="printId">
        test
        <svg height="100" width="100">
            <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" />
        </svg> 
    </div>

    <script src="../../../script/jsPDF/jspdf-2.3.1.umd.min.js" defer></script>
    <script src="../../../script/jsPDF/html2canvas-1.1.2.min.js" defer></script>
    <script>
        function saveAsPDF(divId, usersName, certNumber = '', type = 'old')
        {
        const { jsPDF } = window.jspdf;
        const pdf = new jsPDF();
        var source = document.getElementById("printId");

        pdf.html(
            source, {
            callback: function (pdf) {
                pdf.save("test.pdf");
            },
        });
        }
    </script>
    <input type='submit'
            onclick='saveAsPDF();'
            value='save'>
</body>
</html>
```

I also tried all possible versions of html2canvas:
1.1.2
1.1.5
1.2.2
1.3.2

and two versions of jspdf:
2.1.1
2.3.1

And two browsers: Chrome and Opera.

What can be my issue?

Edit:
I managed to make html2canvas work on it's own with the document below. Now the question is how to make it work with jspdf together:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
            <div id="printId">
                this is circle:
            <svg height="100" width="100">
                <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" />
            </svg> 
            </div>
            <hr>
            <h4>Image of above HTML content...</h4>
            <div id="canvasImg"></div>

    <script src="../../../script/jsPDF/html2canvas-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        html2canvas(document.getElementById('printId')).then(function(canvas) {
            var canvasImg = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg");
            document.getElementById('canvasImg').innerHTML = '<img src="'+canvasImg+'" alt="">';
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like jspdf is not able to add svg as vector graphic to a page. There are three options:

1. Use [svg2pdf](https://github.com/yWorks/svg2pdf.js/) instead of jspdf to convert svg to pdf on it's own.
2. Use [addSvgAsImage](http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/module-svg.html#%7EaddSvgAsImage) function of jspdf to place an svg in the pdf page manually.
3. Convert svg to jpg first, then use jspdf.

I've chosen the 3rd option and wrote a function, which I run before saving canvas as pdf:

```
htmlToJpg: function()
{
    var canvas = document.querySelector('.to-print');
    screenWidth = parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(canvas).width);

    var problematic = document.querySelectorAll('.convert-to-jpg');
    problematic.forEach(function(el) {
        html2canvas(el, 
            {
                scale: 2480/screenWidth // 2480px - size for A4 paper, 300 dpi
            }
        )
        .then(function(canvas) {
            var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
            el.innerHTML = '<img src="' + img + '" class="img">';
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import html2canvas from 'html2canvas';
import { jsPDF as JsPDF } from 'jspdf';
import { useCallback, useEffect } from 'react';

export const useDownloadPdf = (name: string, isReady: boolean) => {
 useEffect(() => {
   if (isReady) {
    const fileName = `${name}.pdf`;
    const pdf = new JsPDF({
    orientation: 'p',
    unit: 'mm',
    format: 'a4',
    putOnlyUsedFonts: true,
    });

    const convertElements = document.querySelectorAll('.convert-on-pdf');
    const elements = Array.from(convertElements) as HTMLElement[];

    if (elements.length > 0) {
      Promise.all(
        elements.map(async (element) => {
          const canvas = await html2canvas(element);
          element.replaceWith(canvas);
      }),
      ).then(() => {
        pdf.html(document.body, {
          callback: (generatedPdf) => {
            generatedPdf.save(fileName)
          },
        });
      });
    } else {
      pdf.html(document.body, {
        callback: (generatedPdf) => {
        generatedPdf
          .save(fileName)
        },
      });
    }
  }
}, [isReady, name, setAtribute]);}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answers given. You can find out more at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page.