# jspdf returns some content in white color

Tags: laravel, vue.js, jspdf

I'm trying to view the contents of my component in pdf.
I receive a pdf correctly but it only prints the title.
When it should print  
it returns me a blank text instead, as if it were not formatted.

Also the content is printed strangely in the pdf (it's very tight.

I am attaching an example file.
[image]

This is the component I am using for the pdf:
https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF

This is the code instead:

```
<div ref="content">
<button class="btn btn-green" @click="downloadPDF">Download PDF</button>

                <div class="container mx-auto items-start md:items-center justify-between px-6 pt-5 md:px-32 md:pt-12 border-t border-gray-200">
                    <div class="border-b border-gray-200">
                        <h4 class="text-3xl font-bold leading-tight text-gray-800 dark:text-gray-100 pb-6">{{ test.title }}</h4> 
                        <ul aria-label="current Status" class="space-y-1.5 text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-400 text-sm">
                            <li class="flex items-center mr-4">
                                <div class="mr-1">
                                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-brand-tabler" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1" stroke="#52525B" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                                        <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"></path>
                                        <path d="M8 9l3 3l-3 3"></path>
                                        <line x1="13" y1="15" x2="16" y2="15"></line>
                                        <rect x="4" y="4" width="16" height="16" rx="4"></rect>
                                    </svg>
                                </div> 
                                <span>Relates to</span>
                            </li> 
                            <li class="flex items-center mr-4">
                                <div class="mr-1">
                                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-edit-circle" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1" stroke="#52525B" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                                        <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"></path>
                                        <path d="M12 15l8.385 -8.415a2.1 2.1 0 0 0 -2.97 -2.97l-8.415 8.385v3h3z"></path>
                                        <path d="M16 5l3 3"></path>
                                        <path d="M9 7.07a7.002 7.002 0 0 0 1 13.93a7.002 7.002 0 0 0 6.929 -5.999"></path>
                                    </svg>
                                </div> 
                                <span>Edit on</span> 
                                <span class="text-gray-400 ml-1">{{ test.updated_at }}</span>
                            </li> 
                            <li class="flex items-center mr-4 pb-8">
                                <div class="mr-1">
                                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-tag" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1" stroke="#52525B" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                                        <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"></path>
                                        <path d="M11 3l9 9a1.5 1.5 0 0 1 0 2l-6 6a1.5 1.5 0 0 1 -2 0l-9 -9v-4a4 4 0 0 1 4 -4h4"></path>
                                        <circle cx="9" cy="9" r="2"></circle>
                                    </svg>
                                </div> 
                                <span>Labels</span> 
                                <span class="btn bg-purple-100 text-purple-700 px-1 py-0 ml-1">{{ test.category }}</span>
                            </li>                                                                 
                        </ul>
                    </div> 
                </div>





              <div>
                <dl>                       
                  <div class="px-6 py-5 md:px-32 md:pt-8 md:pb-20">
                    <dd class="mt-1 text-sm text-gray-900 sm:mt-0 sm:col-span-2">
                        <div v-html="test.content"></div>
                    </dd>
                  </div>
                </dl>
              </div>
            </div>
```

this is the part of script:

```
    downloadPDF() {
const doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
          doc.html(this.$refs.content.innerHTML, {
          callback: function (doc) {
            doc.save('op.pdf');
          },
          x: 1,
          y: 1,
          
        });}
```

Comment: Maybe your text is exported but has a white/#fff color? Your pdf screen shot indicates there is some text in your pdf. Maybe your initial HTML is white text on coloured background?

Comment: @herrstrietzel no, I confirm that the component text is not white. It is seen regularly on the site as well as the title.
When exported, however, the title is printed with the correct color while the rest of the content is white.
In any case, the whole document, as you can see in the photo, appears "narrow" and not full page ...

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by forcing the color with inline styles:

```
style="color:black !important"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, font just went white after a certain point.
The Problem was that I had an css height attribute in on of the outer div's. Deleted it and it just worked, but idk if u have the same issue here.

I suggest u check if one of your outer div's have an css height attribute. If u don't find it just delete one class after another until everything gets displayed correctly. Maybe check first if it gets fixed when you delete all the classes before u go through the work of deleting them one by one ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and my problem was in svg tags, because as of now they are not directly supported by the jspdf function. The [issue](https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF/issues/3161) is already created, somebody is working on it.

In the meanwhile, to make the text not white you can either delete svg file or work around it as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69496770/21664094).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35174001)