# Unable to capture screenshot of SCORM present in Iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, html2canvas, scorm

I am using [Html2Canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) JavaScript library to take screenshot of the SCORM  content rendering in the iFrame. I have Scorm package (it is same html file, css,js file)  file that is loading from the same server so I am not getting any CORS issues, The Scorm is embedded into iFrame to play in the web page.But when I capture the screenshot of the iframe content , I am getting partial content from the page, It ignoring some content, I don't know where I am doing.

```
click_evn = e.target.parentNode;
    html2canvas(click_evn, {
       background: '#fff',
       height: window.innerHeight,
       windowHeight: window.innerHeight,
       logging: true,
       // allowTaint : true,
       // useCORS:true,
       onrendered: function(canvas){
         before_imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
       }
   });
```

**My content of the Scorm in iframe is** 
[image]

**The result of the screenshot**
[image]

Comment: Could it be an svg issue? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/59162619/1464957

Comment: @BrianJ.Miller No, there is no svg , this is normal div with bg color